# Integrating iOS Aviary into iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, aviary

I have successfully integrated iOS Aviary brand new project, but failed to do so on a current working project following the EXACT same steps. (Using XCode 4.5).

I'm getting the error:

```
[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setVisualDefaults]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9869210
```

See image:

[image: Stacktrace attached]

Quick stacktrace:

In the variables under `[AFPhotoEditorCustomization options]` in the stack trace I can see the variables: `resourceBundle` and `path` are both `NIL`.

I suspect this is something with the resource bundle not being read correctly, maybe due to some project/target settings...

Any idea where to look for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem eventually.

Had to set -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-arc linker flags on the TARGETS and not on the project.